# While debugging, how can I start a foreach loop at an arbitrary position in the enumeration?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, foreach

I am debugging my program. Can I set a start object for the `foreach` loop in the debug mode? For instance, I want the `foreach` loop to start from the 5th element of my collection.

Comment: if you can put some code then it would be better

Comment: maybe if your using the `for statement` probably but in foreach?

Comment: maybe conditional breakpoints will fit your needs? So you can change foreach to for and add conditional breakpoint to stop for fifth element or leave foreach loop and then use some other condition.

Comment: @ntl I explained improperly. I mean that I have a collection with, for example, 10000 items. I have an exception in this loop on item 5234. How can I start this loop again from element 5234 without restart a debuging? I do not want to iterate throught all items.

Comment: @Gleb, see my answer below.. just put a break point which will break after hit count = 5234.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cant. Foreach loop uses `IEnumerable<T>` where T is the type of object. So unlike for loop you cannot set initial or start index for the iteration. So you will always start from the 0th location object.

Other option is to use linq as shown below.

```
//Add using System.Linq  statement at top.

int[] numbers = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

foreach(var num in numbers.Skip(5))
{
     Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are talking about debugging I'm assuming what you want to do is to break from the 5th element on etc.  If this is the case then you can use a break point specifying a hit count which will break on the nth hit and so on.

See MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yy96wbwd(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to set the start object is to overwrite the variable that you are enumerating in the loop.

To illustrate, consider the following `foreach` loop.

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
foreach (int n in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

1. Set your breakpoint on the `numbers` statement in the loop initializer, or step to the loop but don't run the `numbers` statement.
2. Use the immediate window to override the value of `numbers`:

   ```
   numbers = numbers.Skip(5);  // or Enumerable.Skip(numbers, 5)
   ```
3. Continue debugging; loop runs from the sixth element.

If your loop uses an inline-computed enumeration as follows, then you're out of luck.  Consider using a [hit-count breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yy96wbwd(v=vs.100).aspx) instead.

```
foreach (int n in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))  // no way to change enumeration.
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Note: once the `numbers` statement is run, the debugger will cache your enumeration so it may no longer be changed and affect the loop.  You may observe this while stepping through the loop construct.

Answer (score 0):

@Shaggy's answer is probably the easiest, but it's good to know that the old fashioned for loop is the fastest, and enables you to skip the 0 index.

```
for(int x = 4; x < numbers.Length; x++)
{
    // Do anything with numbers[x]
}
```

Even though I would not recommend it (It's really bad code), you could make this loop behave different when debugging, as you asked:

```
#if DEBUG
for(int x = 4; x < numbers.Length; x++)
#else
for(int x = 0; x < numbers.Length; x++)    
#endif
{
    // Do anything with numbers[x]
}
```

Comment: Why `numbers.Length - 1`?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: When iterate through any collection of items the first index is always 0, but the length is the actual count of the items. So for convenience, if there are two items in this collection it can iterate from index 0 to 1. If you skip numbers.Length - 1 you must start x from 1 (if index 0 is intended to start from), and use numbers[x-1] when using the item.

Comment: But you're already omitting that value by using `<`. Combining `<` with `len-1` skips the last item.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` does not necessarily operate on a collection which does even have a defined order. consider a `Dictionary<T>` or a `ConcurrentBag<T>`.
so, no, this is not possible in the general case, especially without code changes (which could change the problem you are trying to debug).